# SSRS Report Source Control

Tags: sql-server, svn, reporting-services, version-control

I have several SSRS Reports currently. I want to be able to add all of them to some type of Source Control so I can manage different versions and edits. I was wondering if anyone has had experience adding SSRS Reports to Tortoise SVN or another Source Control besides TFS... All I want to do is be able to see what a user does if he/she changes something in a report and saves over it... I want to be able to retrieve the copy before they saved just in case they break the report. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried VisualSVN with SSRS reports?

Comment: I think I am going to go with TFS actually, I think I should be to use the web GUI to copy all my reports on and have the ability to do what I want. I will look into VisualSVN though, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call me a fossil, but I still use Visual SourceSafe as a repository for my SSRS and SSIS report projects.  It does what you describe pretty much "out of the box", as long as you're diligent about check-ins and labels and such.

This does, of course, raise the question "Is Visual SourceSafe still available/supported?", and I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! But it does look like Visual SourceSafe has been discontinued.

Comment: You're welcome, and that's a shame.  A colleague uses "Git", and he just verified for me that you can get an earlier version of a project from that.  Frankly **any** version control software package should provide the ability to get an earlier version of a project - I just can't speak to any others because I haven't used them.